# Accessing a Riot.js tag's properties from the DOM

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm playing with Riot.js and everything is working great. But let's say I have a page where I mounted this single tag:

```
<so-example>

  <input type="text />

  <script>
    this.disabled = false
  </script>

</so-example>
```

Let's say I want to query this element for one of its properties (e.g. if it's disabled). Neither of these two approaches work:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('so-example')[0].disabled`
2. `document.querySelector('so-example').disabled`

Both of these statements return `undefined`. I want my tag's DOM API to reflect its state, but can't figure out what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who finds themselves in the same situation, the answer is to query the `_tag` property on the element. To access the `disabled` property of the element I used in my original question, you could do this:

```
document.querySelector('so-example')._tag.disabled
```

And that should return the expected `false`. Anything that's defined on `this` within the component can be accessed this way.

Comment: This solution is not using the standard riot.js API and hence may not be future proof. In a future implementation of riot, `_tag` may not stand for what it is now. I would second the solution given by @vitomd: `var s; riot.compile(function() { s = riot.mount('so-example')[0]; }); console.log(s.disabled);`

Comment: @ghd Sadly, `.mount()` doesn't return anything anymore so we're forced to use non-standard API to do useful things.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong for I have never used riot.js and it could do some kind of magic compilation that does that for you, but I doubt it, that sounds like overkill...

Attributes on custom elements don't get bound to their JS representation. You can't use `.disable` as a shortcut because the querySelector or getElementByWhatever function returns a `HTMLUnknownElement` which doesn't have any bound attributes. So you have to use `getAttribute('disabled');` or `hasAttribute('disabled');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It´s depends from where you want to access the property. For instance if it´s from a parent tag, then you can go with. `this.tags.child.message` (to access the message property from the child)

```
<example>
  <child></child>
  <button onclick={access_child}>access child</button>
  <script>
      access_child() {
        console.log(this.tags.child.message) 
      }
  </script>
</example>

<child>
  <script>
      this.message = 'Hello Riot'
  </script>
</child>
```

If you want to access from index.html, you should wrap the mount with `riot.compile` like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    riot.compile(function() {
      var example_tag = riot.mount('example')[0]
      var child_tag = example_tag.tags.child
      console.log('from index: '+child_tag.message)
    })
</script>
```

Here is a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/mjLlDozVzzfcv3Nwl63Y?p=preview